# Why is L2-space convergence important in the definition of the Ito integral?

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

I am currently working through Bernt Oksendals SDE's and I am having some trouble fully understanding the definition of the Ito integral (chapter 3).

My question is this...

> Is there an intuitive explanation as too why in the definition of the Ito integral we require the 'elementary' functions to converge in the L2-space?

Comment: I think because of the quadratic variation of brownian motion converges to $t$ in $L^2$

Comment: We would like a.s. pathwise convergence, but at least in the Ito construction we simply do not have it, there are counterexamples. Since we can't have a.s. pathwise convergence, we might hope for pathwise convergence in measure. We get that. We might further hope for pathwise convergence in $L^p$. We get that in $L^2$ (and thus in all *lower* $L^p$, because probability spaces have finite measure). This is a good thing because it means we can compute expectations and variances of solutions to SDEs as limits of expectations and variances of Markov chains.

Comment: @Ian you say "We might further hope for pathwise convergence in $L^p$ " Why? what is the significance of having convergence in $L^p$? (Apologies, I am fairly new to $L^p$ spaces which is more than likely the root of my confusion)

Comment: Well, as I said, it means that you can approximate expectations and variances of solutions to SDEs by discretizing time and doing Monte Carlo simulations of the associated Markov chain. If you didn't have convergence in $L^1$, neither of these would work; if you had convergence in $L^1$ but not $L^2$ then you could compute expectations but not variances.

Comment: @Ian Thank you, that helped a lot!

Comment: @seraphimk I expanded my comments slightly in an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be great to have a.s. pathwise convergence, but the Ito construction does not provide it for random integrands even when they are non-anticipating. A weaker notion that we might hope for is pathwise convergence in probability. We do get that from the Ito construction. If we are more optimistic, we might hope for pathwise convergence in $L^p$. We do get that for $p=2$ and thus for all $p \leq 2$. This is useful because it means that we can approximate expectations and variances of solutions to an SDE like

$$dX_t=b(X_t) dt + \sigma(X_t) dW_t$$

by computing corresponding expectations and variances of a Markov chain whose increment at a point $x$ is $N(b(x) \Delta t,\sigma(x)^2 \Delta t)$ distributed, for small positive $\Delta t$. (In the vector case, replace $\sigma(x)^2$ by $\sigma(x) \sigma(x)^T$.) If we did not have this convergence in $L^p$ but we did have convergence in measure, that would mean that although most of our samples would behave nicely for small enough $\Delta t$, they would occasionally have large enough errors that that the expectation and variance results would be spoiled by these errors.

There are also some more abstract concepts floating around here relating to it being $L^2$ specifically. For example, because we have convergence in $L^2$, we can make sense of the power spectrum and we can prove the Ito isometry.